# Appending element is not working in IE11

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

In constructor I create an element

```
var this.legendElement = this.compileLegend();
```

and than later I want to use it in event listener:

```
var takeControl = function() {
    this.element.empty();
    this.legendElement.appendTo(this.element);
}
```

legendElement is appended, but it is **empty**! I don't understant why. **In other browsers (tested firefox, chrome) it is working**.

Also when I print content of *this.legendElement* I see html code as expected. In other words

```
console.log(this.legendElement);
```

produces expected html code with correct content (and I call it inside the takeControl function).

I tried several way to fix it

```
this.element.append(this.legendElement)
```

does not work either.

This:

```
this.element.append(this.legendElement.html())
```

appends the html code, but without *this.legendElement* around it (which is expected).

So the following

```
this.element.append($('<div />').append(this.legendElement).html())
```

does what I want it to do, but **it just seems like such an ugly hack**.

So, my question is: What's happening and have can I get

```
this.element.append(this.legendElement)
```

to work?

Thanks in advance! ^_^

Comment: What exactly does `this.compileLegend();` return and what is the structure of  `this.element`?

Comment: this.compileLegend() just fills $('<div />') with subelements and returns it.. some spans and imgs... this.element is just $('<div />')

Comment: I'm having same problem with appending option to select in compatibility mode...

Comment: just load resources for that newly append html item like this:  jQuery.ajaxSetup({ async: false });
        $.get("wwwroot/bootnavbar/bootnavbar.css")
            .done(function () {
                // exists code 

                jQuery.ajaxSetup({
                    async: true

                });

            }).fail(function () {
                // not exists code

                jQuery.ajaxSetup({ async: true });

            });                Here is more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66488564/14491024

Answer (score 14, accepted):

IE11 (at least my version or settings) did not support element.append. It did, however, work as expected with element.appendChild.

The browser compatibility section of MDN confirms that IE (in contrast to every other browser) has never had [ParentNode.append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) support but has always had [Node.appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) support, which appears to be universal.

Comment: Marking this as accepted answer despite not testing it (I am, it's 4 years and that project is long gone...)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the unsupported `el.append()` you should use the universal `el.appendChild()`!

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild
- https://caniuse.com/#search=appendchild

Answer (score 0):

I did not find reason for this error but I bypassed it by constructing element subtree (the compileLegend function) each time when I wanted to append. It required some ugly code to get listeners right but it's the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: If someone finds another solution, I'll gladly make that a accepted answer.