# Bootstrap dropdown not working after initial ajax form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dropdown on my page, `manager.php`, here.  Sorry for the formatting - bootstrap.:

```
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/bootstrapstyle.css">
  <!-- Bootstrap Dropdown Enhancements-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/dropdowns-enhancement.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/dropdowns-enhancement.css">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-primary" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Search By <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul id="searchBy" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li class="disabled"><a href="#">Search By...</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">cost</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">name</a></li>              
        </ul>
      </div>               
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="everything">
</div>
```

**This code works fine when I load `manager.php` directly** and the dropdown initializes, but this is not how I need the code to work.

The user begins on `return.php`; this page collects a bunch of data from the user and *returns* it to `manager.php`.

Once the user selects to do so on `return.php`, this code is run:

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'manager.php',      
      data: {number:number, location:location, project:project, comments:comments},        
        success:function(data){
        $('#everything').html(data);                                                            
        }
  });
```

The ajax call works correctly, and it loads the data returned from `manager.php` into the `everything` div.  It passes along the data as expected.  The only thing that DOESN'T work upon loading `manager.php` into the DIV is the drop-down. I need to understand what I'm doing wrong to cause this functionality so I can prevent doing it in the future.

Comment: because you are probably replacing the html and the events do not magically get hooked back up. You need to rerun the code or learn about event delegation.

Comment: can you provide plunker that reproduced problem?

Comment: Can you post the code that you call to create the dropdown? And have you tried simply recalling `$("#searchBy").dropdown();` in the AJAX callback?

Comment: @tymeJV, the dropdown is the first section of code in my original question.  It operates through bootstrap's dropdown enhancements .css and .js files (http://behigh.github.io/bootstrap_dropdowns_enhancement/)

Comment: @JohnWu -- So have you tried recalling it?

Comment: No - I haven't.  The dropdown isn't made initially with jQuery, so I'm not sure how to "recall it".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to manually reset the dropdown after you've loaded the data into the everything div. I've modified your AJAX call to show you where to put the call.

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'manager.php',      
      data: {number:number, location:location, project:project, comments:comments},        
        success:function(data){
          $('#everything').html(data);
          $('#searchBy').dropdown();
        }
  });
```

The dynamic loading you're doing doesn't cause the DOM to reload forcing the drop down to be reinitialized. After you're AJAX call has completed, you can then reset the bootstrap drop down manually by calling `.dropdown();`.

**EDIT**

Generally functions in bootstrap for features are setup using a `$( document ).ready()` call. This function executes once, after the DOM has been loaded and only after the DOM has has been fully loaded. Since your manipulating the DOM, you are not causing the function to be triggered again, and you need to manually trigger the feature you need.

You also want to load your includes only once on each page. They need to on manager.php in order for the function be available when you go into your success method. I'd suggest using a template for your project so you manage all your includes in one place. Also, if your using manager.php as a page to be included in another page, it's okay if you don't have the reference to the JavaScript pieces won't work since you don't want users accessing that component on it's own.

The reload you are doing appears to be forcing the content to be re-added to the page, thus forcing the `$( document ).ready()` call in the included file to be re-executed. You can do this, but it's very inefficient.

Comment: Yup, tried to delete :).  Unfortunately though, your answer does not cause the dropdown on `manager.php` to function for me.  My answer (below) does work, but I don't understand WHY.

Comment: It seems your logic was indeed correct - we were just focusing on the wrong element.  Adding `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();` after the success call works, but I don't see any difference in the Chrome console (speed-wise) between this solution, and my solution.  But it's really nice having two methods to solve this now; it's been bugging me for months!  Either way, I appreciate the time you've put into this to help me understand this.

Comment: When you say `doesn't cause the DOM to reload`, does that mean the `<head>` section of `manager.php` doesn't get loaded?  I'm not sure what this signifies entirely...

Comment: The head section is part of it, but the entire html document is in the DOM (Document Object Model). Every webpage has it's own DOM that the browser works with and you can manipulate with JavaScript.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model

Comment: perfect!!. Until today , I was defering the loading of bootstrap.js until all my ajax calls complete, with some crappy code.  But now I replaced it with `$('....').dropdown();` Thank you!!

Answer (score 7):

you can't initialize the bootstrap component after page load by adding bootstrap clasaes. To do this you have to initialize it by your self

To initialize a dropdown write this code

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
```

after

```
  $('#everything').html(data);
```

for more details: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns

Comment: This works as well - adding `dropdown()` to the `.dropdown-toggle` class, instead of the `<ul id="searchBy"`.  That's interesting that I can either do this, or force the reload of `bootstrap.js`.  Either way, I appreciate this!  I like having more than one way to accomplish something.

Comment: Yes you can do this but it will re-initialize all the drop-downs on that page having class `.dropdown-toggle`

Answer (score 1):

So I'm not sure why this works, but it has so far:

I've modified my ajax call to reload bootstrap's .js file prior to executing the return.

```
function reload_js(src) {
    $('script[src="' + src + '"]').remove();
    $('<script>').attr('src', src + '?cachebuster='+ new Date().getTime()).appendTo('head');
}

$.ajax({
      ...      
        success:function(data){
        reload_js('https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js');                
        $('#everything').html(data);                                                            
        }
  });
```

For the bounty, can someone explain to me:

a.) Why do I need to force the reload of `bootstrap.min.js`?

b.) Why is this even necessary if I have a link to this file in BOTH files' `<head>` sections?

```
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/bootstrapstyle.css">
```

I've also tried loading it in one, but not the other (so I don't load it twice,) and that doesn't do anything.

c.) Why does this work?  What is it doing?

Answer (score 0):

page will load DOM 1st time. ajax just update a part of page, so new elements you add wont have prop you defined. you need to reinit as you did or make something like this

http://hussain.io/2012/01/reinitializing-jquery-event-on-ajax-response/

Answer (score 0):

I want to share my experience: I am doing dynamical multi layer dropdown menu, meaning that user can customize how many parents and children this menu has. So, after ajax submission, I empty the navbar where the menu is
$(document).find('.navbar-nav').empty();

And fill it with the new html like:
html.push("<li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">" + val.PageName  + "");  // It  is OnTop

and append it to my navbar:
$(".navbar-nav").append(html.join(''));

and the dropdown item is there but it was not working. The reason is that you have to load all the js and css for that new html items again.

Here is the good example os static multilayer menu: https://github.com/kmlpandey77/bootnavbar

So, the main point is after you append new html to the DOM item, you need to reload the page so it to work, or load resources that is that new html items are using;

Here how to load after ajax and append process :

```
        jQuery.ajaxSetup({ async: false });
        $.get("wwwroot/bootnavbar/bootnavbar.css")
            .done(function () {
                // exists code 

                jQuery.ajaxSetup({
                    async: true

                });

            }).fail(function () {
                // not exists code

                jQuery.ajaxSetup({ async: true });

            });
```