# HTML Links do not work after AJAX POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

**Background:** I am working on a small web application. AJAX will successfully POST the data to the action(create.php) and create.php will execute the necessary mysql query. Once AJAX is done, I append a message to the `div id="container"></div>` informing the user of a successful execution then clear the content "container" for future use; however, here in lies the problem.

**Problem:** After AJAX executes, I can not click on any HTML links already loaded onto the page(page.php). I have to refresh the page in order to click on any links and follow them to their destination. What is causing this to happen and how can I fix it?

AJAX does not need to return a result. It only needs to execute the specified jQuery code once the request is done. On a hunch, I altered create.php to echo the $_POST array and have AJAX return that as a result. Once AJAX loads the result into the "container" I still can not click on any links loaded on page.php

**Answer:** The DOM was not being reloaded after AJAX calls causing bootstrap dropdown menus to not function properly. The bootstrap dropdown class had to be manually reinitialized after each call. This has already been answered in detail  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30578971/bootstrap-dropdown-not-working-after-initial-ajax-form-submission)

create.php

```
<?php
if($_POST){
//run mysql query
}else{
//do nothing
}
?>
```

form.php

```
<form id="new-items">
<input type="text" name="item" />
<input type="button" onclick="create_item()" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

page.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#add_items").click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#content").load("form.php");
  });
 });
function create_item(){
    var form_data = $("#new-items").serialize();

    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "create.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: form_data,
    });

    request.done(function(){

        $("#content").append('<div>User was added successfully</div>');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#content").fadeOut("slow");
        }, 5000);
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#content").empty();
        }, 8000);
    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
<a href="link1.php">Link1</a>
<a href="link2.php">Link2</a>
<a href="#" id="add_items">Add New Items</a>
</nav>
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: because your onclick in the php file was rendered prior to being included in the dom where it exists, thus it isn't binded to that function on click.

Comment: `$("#add_items").click(function(){` should be `$("#add_items").click(function(e){` so you can pass the event object for `e.preventDefault`

Comment: to build on @iam-decoder for items created in the dom after the dom has been created you can look up http://api.jquery.com/on/ the on functionality in jquery, I belive this replaced the jQuery live functionality as that has since been deprecated.

Comment: @iam-decoder The .click() functions work fine. That was not my questions. The onclick function create_item() works. After AJAX is done, any `<a href="">TEXT</a>` links in the `<nav>` section do not work without a page refresh.

Comment: @ Blazemonger Yes you are correct, but that in and of itself would not prevent normal HTML links form working

Comment: There is only 1 link in the `<nav>` that I can see. Are the other links being added dynamically?

Comment: @Jackson Updated the code to better reflect more than one link in `<nav>`

Comment: @Unseen your `e` as it stands would throw a reference error though. Notice how the link fails to perform what it should perform in this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/nbfju7eq/)

Comment: @John the jQuery .click() is not the issue. All of my testing and investigating points to AJAX.

Comment: When I copy your code, as provided, I have no trouble clicking the other `nav` links. Your problem, as stated, does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

After you `fadeOut` the `#content` element, it remains hidden. The next time you call your AJAX function, it's loading `create.php` into an invisible element.

Try:

```
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#content").fadeOut("slow", function() {
               $(this).empty().show();
            });
        }, 5000);
```

---

Other issues: `<div class="content">` should be `<div id="content">`; you didn't include `jquery.js` at the top of your script; you didn't pass the event object `e` to your `click` handler.

`page.php` should now look like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#add_items").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#content").load("form.php");
    });
  });
    function create_item(){
        var form_data = $("#new-items").serialize();

        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "create.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: form_data,
        });

        request.done(function(){

            $("#content").append('<div>User was added successfully</div>');
            setTimeout(function(){
                $("#content").fadeOut("slow", function() {
                    $(this).empty().show();
                });
            }, 5000);
        });

        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        });
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav><a href="#" id="add_items">Add New Items</a></nav>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your suggestion works for clearing the `<div id="content"></div>`; however, it does not solve the issue of not being able to click on `<a href="link1.php">Link1</a>` and follow it to where it needs to go.

Comment: As it stands, I'm completely unable to reproduce this problem you're describing.

Comment: Fix the code as I described, and then tell us *exactly* what problem still exists for you. Otherwise, I'm voting to close this question as "unable to reproduce."

Comment: Jquery is included, but omitted in the excerpts on the page. `<div "class">`  was a mistype and correctly shows "id" now. 

I understand passing the event handler (e) down, but can you elaborate on how that would effect other links not related to that?

Comment: No, I can't, because *I can't reproduce that problem at all.* You need to provide us with a [**complete, short, self-contained, correct example**](http://sscce.org/) that shows us the error.

Answer (score 0):

The anchor links in the `<nav>` will natually 'refresh' the page with the new content.

If you want to load the content via an ajax request then you should try the following:

Add a common class to the links

```
<nav>
<a href="link1.php" class="anchor">Link1</a>
<a href="link2.php" class="anchor">Link2</a>
<a href="form.php"  class="anchor">Add New Items</a>
</nav>
```

Then attach a `click` event to each link which intercepts the default page refresh with `e.preventDefault()`. The you can perform the ajax request using the `href` attribute of that link.

```
$(function(){
  $(".anchor").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this=$(this);
    $("#content").load($this.attr('href'));
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it is not on topic with the problem at hand. The issue is not how to load content with AJAX. The issue is that once an AJAX command executes, HTML links on the page are no longer clickable.  For instance, By clicking on "Add New Items" the form loads. Filling in the form and clicking the button submits the data. AJAX completes and appends a message to the div container. The container is then emptied. When I try to navigate to another portion of the site, the links do not work.

Answer (score -1):

The DOM was not being reloaded after AJAX call. Boostrap dropdown module has to be manually reinitialized after each call. Detailed answered here: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30578971/bootstrap-dropdown-not-working-after-initial-ajax-form-submission)