# My bootstrap drown down menu doesn't work after ajax submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a simple login page which logins the user and then redirects them, however I've made a `ajax` code for the reset password page and after I enter the wrong details and the login page reloads the dropdown menu doesn't work.
I've tried to use the `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();` `function` however it's not working at all.

**Login.php**

```
<?php
    require_once('./files/functions.php');
    require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
?>

<html lang="en">

<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>log in</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Vendors -->

        <!-- Animate CSS -->
        <link href="vendors/bower_components/animate.css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Material Design Icons -->
        <link href="vendors/bower_components/material-design-iconic-font/dist/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Site CSS -->
        <link href="css/app-1.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

    <body>
        <div class="login">
            <!-- Login -->
            <div class="login__block toggled" id="l-login">
                <div class="login__block__header">
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-account-circle"></i>
                    Hi there! Please Sign in

                    <div class="actions login__block__actions">
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="zmdi zmdi-more-vert"></i></a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                                <li><a data-block="#l-register" href="">Create an account</a></li>
                                <li><a data-block="#l-forget-password" href="#">Forgot password?</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="login__block__body">
                <form action="" method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group form-group--float form-group--centered form-group--centered">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email">
                        <label>Email Address</label>
                        <i class="form-group__bar"></i>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group form-group--float form-group--centered form-group--centered">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <i class="form-group__bar"></i>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" name="login" value="Sign In" class="btn btn--light btn--icon m-t-15"><i class="zmdi zmdi-long-arrow-right"></i></button>
                    </form>

                <?php
                // some php code for the login process...
            ?>
            </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Forgot Password -->
            <div class="login__block" id="l-forget-password">
                <div class="login__block__header palette-Purple bg">
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-account-circle"></i>
                    Forgot Password?

                    <div class="actions login__block__actions">
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="zmdi zmdi-more-vert"></i></a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                                <li><a data-block="#l-login" href="#">Already have an account?</a></li>
                                <li><a data-block="#l-register" href="#">Create an account</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="login__block__body">
                <form id="pw">
                    <p class="m-t-30">Please enter the e-mail address used to register. We will send your new password to that address.</p>

                    <div class="form-group form-group--float form-group--centered">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="emailfield">
                        <label>Email Address</label>
                        <i class="form-group__bar"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div id="result"></div>
                    <button class="btn btn--light btn--icon m-t-15" value="submit" type="submit"><i class="zmdi zmdi-check"></i></button>
                </div>
                </form>
                <script type = "text/javascript">
    $("form#pw").on("submit", function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        var emailfield = $("#emailfield").val();
        var email ='email='+ emailfield;

        $.ajax({
            url: "login.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: email,
            success: function (result) {
                alert("result: " + result);
                console.log(result);
                $("#result").html(result);
                $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
            }
        });
    });

</script>

<?php
// php code for the reset password....
?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Older IE Warning -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <div class="ie-warning">
                <h1>Warning!!</h1>
                <p>You are using an outdated version of Internet Explorer, please upgrade <br/>to any of the following web browsers to access this website.</p>
                <div class="ie-warning__container">
                    <ul class="ie-warning__download">
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://www.google.com/chrome/">
                                <img src="img/browsers/chrome.png" alt="">
                                <div>Chrome</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/">
                                <img src="img/browsers/firefox.png" alt="">
                                <div>Firefox</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://www.opera.com">
                                <img src="img/browsers/opera.png" alt="">
                                <div>Opera</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="https://www.apple.com/safari/">
                                <img src="img/browsers/safari.png" alt="">
                                <div>Safari</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/download-ie">
                                <img src="img/browsers/ie.png" alt="">
                                <div>IE (New)</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <p>Sorry for the inconvenience!</p>
            </div>
        <![endif]-->


        <!-- Javascript Libraries -->

        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="vendors/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <script src="vendors/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Placeholder for IE9 -->
        <!--[if IE 9 ]>
            <script src="vendors/bower_components/jquery-placeholder/jquery.placeholder.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

        <!-- Site Functions & Actions -->
        <script src="js/app.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap dropdown not working after initial ajax form submission](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30578971/bootstrap-dropdown-not-working-after-initial-ajax-form-submission)

Answer (score 0):

- You are including jQuery twice, once from a CDN and once from the local filesystem.  Remove the CDN one at the top.
- Your inline `<script>` block appears `before` your other Javascript resources are included.  Try placing it after all other JS files, or even better in your `app.min.js` where it probably belongs.

It is hard to see the exact problem bcs so much of your code is your own custom stuff we can't see (and likely has nothing to do with this problem).  In future, please try creating a [minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.