# Jquery append() function is failing in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am Jquery 1.10.2 version. My requirement is to add an xml node at specific node of the already existing xml. For that I am using Jquery append() function. It's working fine in Chrome, Firefox and IE Edge, but failing in IE11.

Getting the following error in IE11:

```
Object doesn't support this property or method
```

The following is the code

```
var effectiveDate = document.getElementById("brokerEffDate").value;
var groupSummaryResponse = soapGetGroupSummary.responseXml.cloneNode(true);


 var userProvidedEffDateNode = "<userProvidedEffDate>"+effectiveDate+"</userProvidedEffDate>";

  if (groupSummaryResponse != null){
            $(groupSummaryResponse).find('divisions').append(userProvidedEffDateNode);
            $(groupSummaryResponse).find('division').each(function(){

                if ($(this).children().get(6).innerHTML == ''){
                    $(this).find('GroupExpDt').text('12/31/9999')
                }

            });
 }
```

What changes do I need to make it work in IE11?

Node.appendChild is also not working in my case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Appending element is not working in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24705352/appending-element-is-not-working-in-ie11)

Comment: @Shree, The accepted answer says to use Node.appendChild , but it's not working too. The same error is repeated.

Comment: Spelling errors? Have you checked that `$(groupSummaryResponse).find('divisions')` does not return `null`? On the line below you've written `'division'` without s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both should work but IE sometime blocks some content if it is running from localhost.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<input type="text" id="brokerEffDate" value="testing" />

<div id="divData1">test div1 </div>

<div id="divData2">test div2 </div>


<script>
var effectiveDate = document.getElementById("brokerEffDate").value;

var divData2 = document.getElementById("divData2");

var userProvidedEffDateNode = "<div>" + effectiveDate + "</div>";
var ele = document.createElement("div");
ele.innerHTML = effectiveDate;

 $("#divData1").append(userProvidedEffDateNode);
 divData2.appendChild(ele);

</script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

**Allow the blocked content**
[image: Allow the blocked content]

**Result. Mostly you will face this issue only when you are running from localhost**
[image: Result]